# Test wordpress https website on localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, https

I am trying to setup HTTPS Protocol on my **Wordpress** website but first, I'd like to test it on localhost, to be sure it will be fine once the website is online. 
I am using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to get self signed certificates .

I want my demo website to be like :

> https://localhost:8080/mywebsite

I tried many things so far but without success :

- Adding this to .htaccess :

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://localhost:8080/mywebsite/$1 [R,L]`

- Added variables to wp-config.php :

`define('WP_HOME', 'https://localhost:8080/mywebsite'); 
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://localhost:8080/mywebsite');
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true); 
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';`

Sometimes I get access to my homepage, but without any images and js (because of wordpress permalink I suppose). Trying to access to other pages give me a `301 Moved Permanantly` error

Comment: Where is your certificate file/key defined? Start by looking at this link: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html

Comment: I don't need one I suppose, I am using ngrok

Comment: try to use full path to css and js in your link tag.

Comment: I always used get_site_url() and wp_enqueue_style() (script for my js too)

Answer (score 1):

In your database, ensure the site URL is correct (including https://) in the options table - by default this table is called wp_options.

Look for the two records where the option_name = siteurl and option_name = home.

Comment: Already checked this on they are both with the same value (http  s://localhost:8080/mywebsite)

Answer (score 1):

> Sometimes I get access to my homepage, but without any images and js (because of wordpress permalink I suppose)

You need to make sure you are loading all resources over https and this includes images. Your browser will block resources that aren't loaded over https.

You will need to do a find and replace on your database to change any entries of http://localhost to https://localhost.

I recommend using [this tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to perform the search and replace as it will account for serialized strings in your database.

Make sure to backup your database before doing the find and replace.

Comment: Do I need to use regex ?

Comment: @rak007 No. Search for `http://localhost` and replace it with `https://localhost`

Comment: Did that, got a Database error when trying to access my website

Comment: Fixed that error but still, nothing appear on my website and when I try to access something else, keep getting 301 error code

Comment: You get a blank white page when accessing the home page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123804/discussion-between-rak007-and-jrod).